# list of all available server controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Just as the title states, can anyone point me to a list of all available asp.net server controls (preferably with descriptions)?  I would have thought that something like this would be readily available but I've had no luck finding this.  I almost always have to dig around to find a control to solve a particular problem, a quick reference would be really handy.

Comment: MSDN has a grouped hierarchy of ASP.NET controls available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386416.aspx

Comment: All? Do you mean MS provided? In the BCL only? Outside? Third party?

Comment: Oded MS provided, I typically stick to framework provided controls as well as the Ajax toolkit controls.

Comment: Anthony that's a good starting point, I was hoping there would be some sort of matrix out there that one could print out!  Wishful thinking on my part!

Answer (score 2):

MSDN has a list from the Framework Documentation, it has links to descriptions and examples for all the controls (see the classes list).  The list has a few extra items in it from some of the controls EventArgs classes and such.  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bhzsw6t(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bhzsw6t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Ben that's another good resource, just not as concise as I would hope.